# visual studio test agent delpoyment task fail with message 'Did not find TestAgentConfig.exe

Tags: tfs-2015

I have two PC, both are win7 installed. 
I want to build a automatic test platform using TFS.
I want to use PC1 as TFS server, I have Microsoft TFS 2015, Visual studio 2015 installed.

and in PC2, I have Visual studio 2015 installed, I want the PC2 to be testing PC( include Coded UI test)

I create one Build in clude

```
1# Visual Sutodio Build task
2# Windows Machine file Copy 
3# Visual studio test agent delpoyment
4# Run functional test.
```

once I running the build I will get following message error at step 3#

```
DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' for machine apcnopc7pm5z2x:5985's Error : System.Exception: Did not find TestAgentConfig.exe at : C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TestAgentConfig.exe. Ensure that TestAgent is installed.
```

anything wrong with me? can anybody help me ?
[screenshot of the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwsOY.png)

Comment: Have you tried installing the agent manually?

Comment: Yes, that not work

Comment: Are you using a x64 version OS? If yes, can you check if the file exist in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE" folder?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install the test agent on PC2. Just uninstall the test agent. All you need is add task [Visual studio test agent deployment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/DeployVisualStudioTestAgent/README.md) with the remote machine (PC2) information supplied. This task will deploy “Test Agent” to the machine and configure it automatically.

Please notice, this task requires the target computer to have:

- Windows 7 Service Pack 2 or Windows 2008 R2 or higher
- .NET 4.5 or higher
- PSRemoting enabled by running the [Enable-PSRemoting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849694.aspx) PowerShell script

Comment: You environment doesn't meet the requirement. You need at least win7 SP2.